# java.lang.RuntimeException: NotImplemented at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch.createChart(HSSFPatriarch.java:518)

Tags: java, excel, charts, backslash

> java.lang.RuntimeException: NotImplemented    at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch.createChart(HSSFPatriarch.java:518)

```
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 20);

Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor); // Error got here
```

i am using jar file poi-3.11-beta2.jar

Comment: Yes [HSSFPatriarch.createChart](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPatriarch.html#createChart%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor%29) is not implemented until now. And it is also tagged as such in API docs.

Comment: @AxelRichter what should i do now?  I have to create a chart in excel sheet which will be created using HSSF

Comment: .xlsx not possible to use? also there is poi 3.15 available

Comment: What shall I say? Either you will wait until `HSSFPatriarch.createChart` will be implemented from apache poi developer team or you will implement your own createChart method using the low level objects (not really easy for the binary `*.xls` `BIFF` formats) or you forget the ancient `*.xls` format and will using `*.xlsx` Office Open XML format. `XSSFDrawing.createChart` is implemented already.