# Getting error when creating a Bar Chart in Excel with Apache POI with Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, apache-poi

**Exception** : `java.lang.RuntimeException: NotImplemented at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch.createChart(HSSFPatriarch.java:526).`

**Code:**

```
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, courses.size(), courses.size(), 30);
Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor); // Getting error here.
CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart) chart).getCTChart();
CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
ctBoolean.setVal(true);
ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.COL); ..........
```

**Maven file:**

```
org.apache.poi(3.15), 
poi-ooxml(3.15), 
poi-ooxml-schemas(3.15), 
ooxml-schemas (1.3)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42154420/624003

Comment: What kind of file are you working on? `XLS` with `HSSF` or `XLSX` with `XSSF`?

Comment: Its an .xls file @Gagravarr.
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"report.xls\"");

Comment: Almost all the code you have posted is only for working with `XSSF` on `XLSX` files! It will therefore never work... What happens if you swap to the newer XLSX format?

Comment: can i have a sample code from  your side @Gagravarr .